# Q: My Unity2D code is using world's center instead of object's position and I don't know why

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

I made this code for bullet to cast a ray from it's position to player's position and then move to the point of ray collision:

`hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, playerTransform.position, boundariesMask);`

But the problem is, the code casts a ray not from bullet's position but from world's center which is (0,0). What do I do?
UPD: Just wanted to share that when I debug bullet's position it gives me right result, but it seems like it can't use bullet's position for raycasting for some reason...

Comment: Where is the object with the code on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that no any `overload` is provided for Raycast similar to what you have defined. For this reason, it is possible to consider the layer value for the ray distance. To solve the problem, set the ray distance before defining the layer. If the ray distance is unlimited, you can use `Mathf.Infinity`.

```
hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, playerTransform.position, 10f, boundariesMask.value);

if (hit)
{
    // do something..
}
```